# Rails Active Record order with parameters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to provide parameters to `.order` in Rails? You can provide parameters to `.where`.

For example:

```
People.where("age > :min_age and age < :max_age", {:min_age => 20, :max_age: 80})
```

Doing this with `.order` translates differently to sql.

For example:

```
Places.order("pow(lat - :mylat,2) + pow(lon-:mylon,2)", {:mylat => 1, :mylon => 2})
```

translates into the following sql which gives a sql syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM places ORDER BY pow(lat - :mylat,2) + pow(lon - :mylon,2) '---\n:mylat: 1\n:mylon: 2\n'
```

I know you can sort an array using `.sort_by`. I would like to know if you can do this using the .order function in Active Record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer short: no it does not.

You have to write you own implementation which would strictly verify the values of parameter and building your order string

Be careful with this because `order` does not sanitize parameters, unlike `where` does

```
> User.order('1; select * from users')
=> SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`   ORDER BY 1; select * from users
```

Comment: Thanks. It's weird that .where and .order do not share this functionality.

Comment: I'm writing a gem to answer this problem, it works on whitelist and accept parameter to order and filter records. It works but sadly I have not written any documentation yet, so I cannot release it just yet.